# Optimize sql query to get duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

A have a following sql query:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users users

WHERE users.name <> '' and users.email <> '' and users.phone <> ''

and users.name in (  SELECT name
            FROM users
                where name <> '' and name is not null
            GROUP BY name
            HAVING count(name) > 1 )
and users.email in (  SELECT email
            FROM users
                where email <> '' and email is not null
            GROUP BY email
            HAVING count(email) > 1 )
and users.phone in (  SELECT phone
            FROM users
                where phone <> '' and phone is not null
            GROUP BY phone
            HAVING count(phone) > 1 )
ORDER BY users.name+users.email+users.phone ASC
LIMIT 0,200
```

Which unfortunately run very slow on huge database. Is there any option to optimize this query?

Idea for query result: get all records that has duplicates in database (for example get users with same name+same phone+same email

I tried with inner join but seems not work correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want users with the same name, phone, and email, then use `group by`:

```
select u.name, u.phone, u.email, group_concat(u.user_id)
from users u
group by u.name, u.phone, u.email
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you want all rows, rather than just the ids in a list, then use `join`:

```
select u.*
from (select u.name, u.phone, u.email
      from users u
      group by u.name, u.phone, u.email
      having count(*) > 1
     ) udup join
     users u
     on u.name = udup.name and u.phone = udup.phone and u.email = udup.email
order by u.name, u.phone, u.email;
```

Note:  These queries do not do what your original query does.  Instead, it is based on the logic you describe in the text ("for example get users with same name+same phone+same email").

Comment: @ПавелИванов . . . The second query is actually ANSI standard SQL that should work in any database.  The first uses `group_concat()` which was pretty much invented when MySQL was invented.

Comment: perfect never mind that having count(*) > 1 and multiple grouping will work. thanks.

Comment: one problem I have, If i run second query only by grouping by name it uses 90sec to execute statement. If name+surname 70sec, but if all it get results for 5-10s. (table is atleast 70k records). Is this is normal behaviour?

Comment: @ПавелИванов . . . An index on `users(name, phone, email)` should help performance.